# Why is hyphenation not working with lang en

Tags: html, hyphenation

What is wrong with this code that hyphenations don't work for `lang="en"`?

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  hyphens: auto;
}

div {
  max-width:200px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 lang="en">Kindofverylongheadlineevenbiggerthanimagined</h1>
  <h1 lang="en">Internationalization</h1>
  <h1 lang="de">Kindofverylongheadlineevenbiggerthanimagined</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hyphenation rules are language-specific. In HTML, the language is determined by the lang attribute, and browsers will hyphenate only if this attribute is present and the appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)

Comment: If look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) it says a couple of things: 1. `You must specify a language using the lang HTML attribute to guarantee that automatic hyphenation is applied in that language.` 2. `browsers will hyphenate only if this attribute is present and the appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available` 3. It is possible that you are setting correct bounds for your text container.

Comment: Note all the notes regarding browser support on [caniuse.com's support listing for the property](https://caniuse.com/css-hyphens).

Comment: @Lae please don't use code formatting for emphasis or quoting. Use it for code.

Comment: Wondering why I see the German text hyphenated but not the English

Comment: Was just noticing that.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319971/why-hyphens-dont-work-with-inner-span)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why hyphens don't work with inner <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319971/why-hyphens-dont-work-with-inner-span)

Comment: I voted duplicate and tried some of the answers there, but they didn't then, and still don't seem to fix the problem. Win/Firefox and Chrome.